AWS RDS DB Migration
I have a PostgresFB on an AWS RDS instance that we want to migrate to an on-site server. The problem we having is the migrating of data and the time it is taking to migrate the data.
I have tried AWS migration and that is taking an hour to do 100mb just imagine the time if it is as 80GB DB.
If I do a backup and compress I can get the DB down to 47GB and then using AWS Data sync and that is only transfer it at 1mb a second so going to take quite a while to transfer.
What other suggestions is there for me to get this db either sync faster or get the data out of AWS faster?
Any suggestions from experience?

There is logical replication, but it is complicated, and if your hosted database is as lame as it seems to be, it might not work well either. Perhaps you have to buy more I/O or whatever is the bottleneck from Amazon. They like your money and want to keep you as a customer.

Solution really depends on how many time you can stop the service, is it a concern for you or not ?

I think your bottleneck is related to the network throughput from AWS to other Data Centers.  I don’t have any visibility about your network bandwidth between the AWS and other data centers. The suggestion of course set up reliable network connectivity to be reliably compared to the existing one. You can set up a Site-to-Site VPN or use AWS Direct Connect to your data centers.
The ideal way how to migrate the RDS PostgreSQL database into the onsite server is by creating a replication/synchronization of data instead of a one-time migration. You can achieve that by:

Set up logical replication from RDS PostgreSQL to the database instance on-premise.

Uses Amazon DMS to replicate the data from RDS to the other database instance. Check out this article


How long the process it will take?. Back again, it depends on the network throughput, eventually if you set the sync, it will catch up the data and after there is no lagging / the data is identical, you can switch to using the data on-premise.
